# Why does "HAVING" statement with "REPLACE" affects the values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with "tag" and "category" columns. The tags may contain spaces, but I want to filter them by a query string that has dashes instead of the spaces (it comes from a URL slug).

I run the following query on mysql:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS tags
FROM tags 
GROUP BY category 
HAVING REPLACE( tags,  ' ',  '-' ) like "%a%"
```

The result is:

```
first-tag,second-tag
third-tag,fourth-tag
fifth-tag
```

Could someone explain why do the tags that are returned have dashes as well? I would expect (and hope) for the REPLACE to be used for the filtering by the HAVING statement, but the original value to be returned by the query. How would I achieve that?

Here's a fiddle for your reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7573/1

Thank you!

EDIT (by gordon):

For those interested, this problem occurs in this simpler version of the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS tags
FROM tags 
HAVING REPLACE(tags, ' ', '-') is not null;
```

As @Razvan points out, this is a reference issue.  It doesn't happen with the `group_concat()` directly in the `having`.

Comment: As a workaround you can use the expression instead of the alias and it will work fine: `... HAVING REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT(tag SEPARATOR  ',' ),  ' ',  '-' ) like "%a%"`

Comment: Ah! Nice! Thanks Razvan, didn't think of this solution. There is a small performance impact of doing this calculation twice though, isn't there?

Comment: I assume there will be, but I'm really not sure how MySQL handles the second GROUP_CONCAT expression considering that it was already evaluated before.

Comment: @Sasha . . . You can fix it more easily by doing `having tags like '%a%'`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your suggestion loses the REPLACE functionality that I need. The query might be "first-tag", and this will result in an empty set. Replacing the dashes in the query back to spaces will not cut it either, since some tags might actually have dashes in them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is very intersting, I think you should just fill a bugreport to MySQL.
They have a proprietary extensions which modifies the behavior of `HAVING`.
For example: [The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

And since your case is not a real scenario (because you don't actually need `REPLACE` here), I think that this is worth mention, that [in case of simple '%%' `LIKE` patern](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d7573/5) it does not change the results. Or, if you [add `OR 1` to `HAVING` clause](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d7573/6), it will also display the correct results.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I didn't know the standard details. I'm not sure why do you say it's not a real scenario - this is something I actually need for my project (of course there might be better solutions!). Adding "OR 1" changes the logic, and I believe mysql is smart enough to understand there is no need to evaluate the first part - this is probably why it doesn't affect the results.

Comment: @Sasha You are welcome. I don't see why you need to use `REPLACE` for this `LIKE` compare - that is why I say this is not a real scenario.

Comment: I used "%a" as an example, may be a bit too simplistic. In a real world scenario I would want to serve a url of "/tags/first-tag" (instead of the ugly and may be less SEO friendly "/tags/first%20tag") and need to fetch all the entries that are tagged with "first tag". Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: @Sasha Well, I don't see why you need `HAVING` than :) You can just use conditions in `WHERE` clause. If you can't - post another question with your real world scenario, and some sample data. But this one is good as it is :)

Comment: Heh, it's getting interesting :) Well, it's because for each tagged item I want to fetch ALL its tags (the original query is a bit more complicated, with a couple of JOINs). So I need to first build a list of all the tags for each item (that's the GROUP_CONCAT) and then fetch only those that contain the tag. That needs to happen after the grouping, hence the usage of HAVING.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Yes, I followed @Razvan's suggestion for a workaround, and it did the work for me.